# Escape inline css in c#

Tags: c#, css

I am trying to scape the follow snippet of inline styling for a html enabled email:

```
addressInformation.Append("<style> p {font-family:"Calibri", "Arial";} </style>");
```

I have tried escaping the double quotes with additional double quotes and curly braces with additional curly braces to no avail.

How do I Escape this line?

Comment: Did you try "/"" for quotes ?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but from a software design perspective, this isn't a good way to do styling. Please use css classes.

Comment: @Erwin, I know this isn't good but its for an email which is rendering as html, which I am constructing the body using StringBuilder. Is there a better way of referencing a style sheet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two choices:

```
addressInformation.Append("<style> p {font-family:\"Calibri\", \"Arial\";} </style>");

addressInformation.Append(@"<style> p {font-family:""Calibri"", ""Arial"";} </style>");
```

And of course you can also bypass the need to escape:

```
addressInformation.Append("<style> p {font-family:'Calibri', 'Arial';} </style>");
```

Or in this case, since the values are single words:

```
addressInformation.Append("<style> p {font-family:Calibri, Arial;} </style>");
```

Answer (score 4):

`"` is escaped with `\"`

```
addressInformation.Append("<style> p {font-family:\"Calibri\", \"Arial\";} </style>");
```

Answer (score 3):

' character should work, or \" instead of just ".

`addressInformation.Append("<style> p {font-family:'Calibri', 'Arial';} </style>");`
`addressInformation.Append("<style> p {font-family:"Calibri", "Arial";} </style>");`